# What's the name of the Niffler?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts

What's the name of the Niffler owned by Newt Scamander in Fantastic Beasts & Where To Find Them?

Comment: Bob.  Bob Niffler.

Answer (score 8):

Disappointingly, it doesn't appear to have a name, other than "Niffler" or "The Niffler" (depending on whose perspective we're looking from).

> *As Newt looks up toward Mary Lou, something seen from the corner of
> his eye catches his attention. **The Niffler**, a small, furry black cross
> between a mole and a duck-billed platypus, is sitting on the steps of
> the bank, hastily pulling the beggar’s hat full of money out of sight
> behind a pillar.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Where-Find-Them/dp/1408708981)</sup></sub>

and

> **NEWT:**
> [annoyed] *Bugger — **Niffler’s gone**. Of course he has, little bugger. Any chance to
> get his hands on something shiny.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them: The Original Screenplay](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fantastic-Beasts-Where-Find-Them/dp/1408708981)</sup></sub>

Comment: Interesting, seeing as a lot of the other beasts had names.

Comment: @ibid - Some did, some didn't.

Comment: it's name is probably like Ash's pikachu

Comment: The name also never appears in any of the DVD extras.